# GCloud Vision API Permission Denied on Second Request

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-vision

I've gone through all the setup steps to make calls to the Google Vision API from a Node.js App. Link to the guide: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#setting_up_authentication

I'm using the `ImageAnnotatorClient` from the `@google-cloud/vision` package to make some text detections.

At first, it looked like everything was set up correctly but I don't know why it only allows me to do one request.

Further requests will give me the following error:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the vision.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
```

If I restart the Node app it again allows me to do one request to the Vision API but then the subsequent requests keep failing.

Here's my code which is almost the same as in the examples:

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const detectText = async (imgPath) => {
  // console.log(imgPath);
  const [result] = await client.textDetection(imgPath);
  const detections = result.textAnnotations;
  return detections;
}
```

It is worth to mention that this works every time when I run the Node app in my local machine. The problem is happening on my Ubuntu Droplet from Digital Ocean.

Again, I set everything up as it is in the guides. Created a Service Account, downloaded the Service Account Key JSON file, set up the environment variable like this:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="PATH-TO-JSON-FILE"
```

I'm also setting the environment variable in the .bashrc file.

What could I be missing? Before setting up everything from scratch and go through the whole process again I thought it would be good to ask for some help.

Comment: The error suggests that you either didn't create the service account as desribed in the documentation *or* you're referencing the wrong service account credentials. That it works on your local machine suggests the credentials are correctly referenced there and not from the droplet. You don't include the reference that you cite. Are you referring to this page? https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#setting_up_authentication

Comment: Yes, thanks! I'll add that to the question. As I mentioned. The first request from the Droplet works, then the other ones fail. Shouldn't everything fail from the beginning if it wasn't set up correctly? It seems pretty weird that it allows me to do one request. Anyway, I think I'm gonna do everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem. In my case, it was a problem with PM2 not passing the system env variables to the Node app.

So I had everything set up correctly auth-wise but the Node app wasn't seeing the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var.

I deleted the PM2 process, created a new one and now it works.